# How to display project, group members and their boss side by side in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pivot, rdbms

I want to show (team id, team name, intern id, intern name, reporter id, reporter name) for all my records. I don't know how to separate interns in one column and reporters in another for same team. I want to do this because I want each reporter to provide evaluation for each intern they are working with in that group.
[image: Image of my table]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We very much prefer to see sample data as *text* in questions rather than images. Even better is a demo on sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com.

Comment: What result set do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a join with sub query for Intern and Reporter

```
select a.teamID, a.temaName, 
  b.peopleID intren_id, b.firstname intern_name, b.lastname inter_lastname, 
  c.peopleId, c.firstname reporter_name, c.lastname reporter_lastname
from mytable a  
inner join  (
  select teamId, firstname, lastname
  from mytable 
  where pType = 'Intern'
) b on a.teamId  = b.teamId 
inner join  (
  select teamId, firstname, lastname
  from mytable 
  where pType = 'Reporter'
) c on a.teamId  = c.teamId
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want columns that are vertical "lists".  This is not really a relational structure, because the values in the rows don't relate to each other.

However, you can do it using conditional aggregation.  However, you need to enumerate the values.  In MySQL 8+, this is easy using `row_number()`, so the query looks like:

```
select teamid, teamname,
       max(case when ptype = 'intern' then peopleid end) as intern,
       max(case when ptype = 'reporter' then peopleid end) as reporter
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by teamid, ptype order personid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by teamid, teamname, seqnum;
```